Cloth modifer passing through collision object/sliding off
I have been struggling learning the physics of the cloth modifier in Blender. I am trying to create a "teaser" image where the cloth is covering my object and you can just see the outlines of the object under it as the cloth is acting as a veil over it.
However, after watching many videos I still have the issue of the clothing passing through parts of the object, and falling off like a wind is blowing it.
I am also confused as to how to get the cloth the right physics so that it is sticking around the object so one can see the obeject shape outlines below it.
https://we.tl/t-iFXV3EJmpp

Please don't use an external link for your file which won't be available to folks researching your question in future. You can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. An image of your current Blender screen showing your settings would also be helpful. You can create a screenshot via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu and then add it to your question with the editing tools.

Increase the Collisions Quality of the cloth:


gonna do this...Thank you so much for checking!

@Madi This site is not a regular forum,  please don't  reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead upvote the post that helped you. If you feel it completely solved your issue consider marking it as accepted.
